# Error post updating and installing nightly packages. locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I updated my sim to try the damping tutorial for Sandia Hands and DRC Sim wont start thereafter.
Error keeping looping and trying to start and spawn the worlds and models.
Log can be seen below:

```
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [9927]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 9927, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rosout/bin/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/sudip/.ros/log/49d503dc-c584-11e2-ae97-4c809313301c/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/sudip/.ros/log/49d503dc-c584-11e2-ae97-4c809313301c/rosout-1*.log
respawning...
[rosout-1] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [9929]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 9929, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rosout/bin/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/sudip/.ros/log/49d503dc-c584-11e2-ae97-4c809313301c/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/sudip/.ros/log/49d503dc-c584-11e2-ae97-4c809313301c/rosout-1*.log
respawning...
[rosout-1] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3008/error-post-updating-and-installing-nightly-packages.-locale::facet::_s_create_c_locale-name-not-valid/) by [Sudip_Gupta](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/326/sudip_gupta/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[Looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922713/valid-locale-names) a problem with your locale setting.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0